# What is the linguistic term for re-writing a dialect text to standard language?

Tags: terminology

**What is the linguistic term for re-writing a written text from non-standard dialect to standard dialect of the same language?**

> [Translation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Translation_(disambiguation)) is the conversion of text from one **language** to another.

Since we keep the same language, and just change the dialect, I would rule out *translation*.

> [Transliteration](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transliteration) is a type of conversion of a text from one script to another that **involves swapping letters** (thus trans- + liter-) in predictable ways (such as α → a, д → d, χ → ch, ն → n or æ → e).

We stay in the same script and don't swap letters, so this doesn't seem to fit either.

Is there a separate term at all, or do linguistics use a broader definition for *translation* in such a case?

Comment: You should give an actual example or link to examples of this rewriting.  Otherwise we cannot say.  For example there is Alemannic, and then there is just *geschwobtes deutsch*.  Anyway technically it all still falls under translation (and in my work I say *variant translation*), but maybe there is also a more specific word.

Comment: @AdamBittlingmayer Better? (I hope, the actual dialect or group of dialects doesn't matter.) -  I have no clue, what _geschwobtes deutsch_ means, never heard this before and couldn't find it. Could you please enlighten me? - And thank you for suggesting _variant translation_ :)

Comment: Yes, better, although I would also include an example in a quote in the question.

Comment: *geschwobtes Deutsch* is something like that produced by the Schwobifying Proxy, which is more of a superficial conversion, like a gloss.

Comment: The examples you provided aren't of a dialect vs a language, but of a regional language vs a standard language. Bavarian doesn't have "an army and a navy" but that doesn't mean much linguistically. Your own Wikipedia link calls it "Bavarian *language*", not "Bavarian *dialect*". You probably wouldn't have any issues using the term "translation" if it came to turning Swedish into Norwegian, and yet Swedish and Norwegian (or some varieties of them, anyway) are much closer to each other than Bavarian is to Standard German.

Comment: @LjL I started on the German version of the Wikipedia page, which is called "Bairsche Dialekte" and I didn't notice the change. Thanks for pointing out! I'll try to figure out, whether dialect/Dialekt is some sort of [false friend](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/False_friend) or similar.... Very strange...

Comment: @Marzipanherz there has long been a tendency to demote [regional languages](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regional_language) into just "dialects" (or the local standard language's equivalent of the word) in many countries in Europe: see the French word "patois" being used even for [Occitan](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Occitan_language), or the Italian "dialetto" being used for the many diverse [Romance languages spoken in Italy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Languages_of_Italy). Linguistically, even though the distinction is still tricky, dialects are defined by mutual intelligibility.

Comment: @LjL The trouble is that linguistically, dialects and languages aren’t defined at all. There are many cases of dialects not being mutually intelligible, especially at opposite ends of dialect spectrums, and just as many of languages being perfectly mutually intelligible. Many regional languages are still considered to ‘belong to’ a more standardised official language, and translating from one to the other is definitely a thing, regardless of how we classify each.

Comment: I would disagree that they aren't *defined*; I would agree that the definitions don't cover all cases perfectly, just like, for that matter, the language tree model, as commonly accepted in linguistics, doesn't cover all cases perfectly at all. If ultimately we are here to determine what term is best when converting from lect A to lect B, then I would agree that "translation" should be applicable to dialects and languages alike.

Answer (score 5):

The distinction between "language" and "dialect" isn't always clear. See, for example, the Mandarin and Cantonese "dialects" of Chinese, which are far more distinct than the Serbian and Croatian "languages".

As such, I'd use "translation", whether it's dialects or languages involved.

Comment: This also has some currency: https://www.google.com/search?q=machine+translation+for+closely+related+language+pairs

Comment: The question specified standard vs. non-standard dialect in the same language.  Mandarin and Cantonese clearly don't apply in those circumstances.   They are clearly two languages.  The question is asking about the use of language among non-dominant groups vs. the dominant group, such as in the use of English among minority groups vs what is considered standard dialectical English.